# Django test chooses database randomly

Tags: python, django, database, master-slave

I have multiple database settings (master/slave) as follow:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.parse('postgres://localhost:5432/master_db'),
    'slave': dj_database_url.parse('postgres://localhost:5432/slave_db'),
}
```

Slave database is only used explicitly for some offline expensive query (with `objects.using` and is not used any of testcases.
As noted in [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/multi-db/#defining-your-databases) 'default' database is used when there is no database specified explicitly.
The problem is when I run `python manage.py test --keepdb` it sometimes run tests with `slave` database which raises error (because there is no table created in `slave` databse).

The output of `python manage.py test --keepdb` when  it uses `slave`:

```
Using existing test database for alias 'slave'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "categorization_category" does not exist
LINE 1: ...rization_category"."last_modified_date" FROM "categoriz...
```

The output of when  it uses `default`:

```
# some ..... and warnings showing tests are running
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
# some debug info in tests
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
Ran 119 tests in 91.456s

OK
```

How can I force test to use only 'default' database as test database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your settings:

```
DATABASES['slave']['TEST'] = {
    'MIRROR': 'default',
}
```

[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/advanced/#topics-testing-advanced-multidb) you can read why.

Comment: It only redirect slave database to master but why it's not using 'default' database for test?